# Fill e.layer when firing events manually

Tags: leaflet, features, events, vector-tiles, vector-layer

(Asked on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44053812/688080), but later found gis@stackexchange, and think it may be a more suitable place)

I am using a [`L.vectorGrid.protobuf`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid) layer (named as `pbfLayer`) to display vector tiles, and I want to trigger click events by `pbfLayer.fileEvent('click', {latlng: <some coordinate>})`. But if in this way the event argument `e` will only have properties `latlng`, `target`, and `type`, while if triggered manually by mouse clicking it will have more properties including `layer`.

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/ziyuang/dfekwzhd/

Every time a click event is triggered, the console will print the event argument `e`. A screenshot of console output is as follow, if I first trigger an event manually by clicking and then by programming, using the same coordinate:

[image: demo-points]

Is there a way to find and fill other properties of `e`, so that `fireEvent` can perfectly mimic a clicking?

---

(https://jsfiddle.net/ziyuang/dfekwzhd/4/):

I tried [prosthetic-hand](https://github.com/Leaflet/prosthetic-hand) for mimicking mouse clicking but still not working. The code added is

```
var crs = L.CRS.EPSG3857;
var rambaut_lake_latlng = L.latLng(40.99842740667731,-74.16458129882814);
var rambaut_lake_point = crs.latLngToPoint(rambaut_lake_latlng , map.getZoom());
var southwest_point = crs.latLngToPoint(map.getBounds()._southWest, map.getZoom());
var x = rambaut_lake_point.x - southwest_point.x;
var y = map.getSize().y - (southwest_point.y - rambaut_lake_point.y);
console.log([x, y])

var hand = new Hand();
var finger = hand.growFinger('mouse');
finger.moveTo(x, y, 0).down().up();
```

Manually clicking will create a popup of "Rambaut Lake" but I don't see any popup on the page.

---

I finally get this done by using [happen](https://github.com/tmcw/happen). 
In my case, I have to

```
var canvas = document.elementFromPoint(left, top);
$(canvas).happen({type: 'click', clientX: left, clientY: top});
```

And neither `$('#map').happen({type: 'click', clientX: left, clientY: top})` nor using jQuery's [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) on the found `canvas` works for me.

Comment: Cross post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44053812/fill-e-layer-when-firing-events-manually

Comment: Why is it off-topic?